scala in emacs: lsp server fails to start due to semgrep-ls server startup failure related to yojson and git rev-prse
Attempting to set up lsp-metals in emacs. My emacs config, verbatim from the lsp-metals emacs page:
(use-package lsp-metals
  :ensure t
  :custom
  ;; You might set metals server options via -J arguments. This might not always work, for instance when
  ;; metals is installed using nix. In this case you can use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable.
  (lsp-metals-server-args '(;; Metals claims to support range formatting by default but it supports range
                            ;; formatting of multiline strings only. You might want to disable it so that
                            ;; emacs can use indentation provided by scala-mode.
                            "-J-Dmetals.allow-multiline-string-formatting=off"
                            ;; Enable unicode icons. But be warned that emacs might not render unicode
                            ;; correctly in all cases.
                            "-J-Dmetals.icons=unicode"))
  ;; In case you want semantic highlighting. This also has to be enabled in lsp-mode using
  ;; `lsp-semantic-tokens-enable' variable. Also you might want to disable highlighting of modifiers
  ;; setting `lsp-semantic-tokens-apply-modifiers' to `nil' because metals sends `abstract' modifier
  ;; which is mapped to `keyword' face.
  (lsp-metals-enable-semantic-highlighting t)
  :hook (scala-mode . lsp))

Opening a hello world scala file (or starting scala-mode) produces an error in the minibuffer
Server semgrep-ls:1389372 exited (check corresponding stderr buffer for details). Do you want to restart it? (y or n) 

The corresponding *semgrep-ls:stderr* buffer contains
Process semgrep-ls stderr finished
Fatal error: exception Git_wrapper.Error("run ['git' '-C' '/home/jake/src/helloworld' 'rev-parse'\n     '--is-inside-work-tree']: No such file or directory")
Raised at Yojson__Safe.__ocaml_lex_read_object_sep_rec in file "lib/read.mll", line 698, characters 13-43
Called from Yojson__Safe.__ocaml_lex_read_json_rec in file "lib/read.mll", line 226, characters 23-47

This looks like it's coming from ocaml's yojson library, but I don't know why it's issuing a git rev-parse command or what file or directory it claims doesn't exist, because that filepath does exist.
Any idea what I could investigate next?
Or - has anyone gotten lsp-metals working in emacs lately that could provide any setup tips? I'm on arch linux and installed semgrep using these instructions:
https://snapcraft.io/install/semgrep/arch#install
semgrep lsp starts fine when I start it myself:
$ semgrep lsp --debug
[00.00][DEBUG]: Logging setup for osemgrep
[00.00][DEBUG]: Executed as: osemgrep lsp --debug
[00.00][DEBUG]: Starting semgrep-lsp
[00.00][DEBUG]: Starting Semgrep Language Server

Attempting to open scala-mode with that running improves nothing - I was hoping it would use the running server.
EDIT:
Disabling the semgrep-ls client got things working. Leaving this question here in case someone does have any clues, because presumably semgrep provides value worth enabling?
(setq lsp-disabled-clients '(semgrep-ls))


You may ask in their official discord server: https://discord.gg/3eHeFJ2XhJ

I don't use lsp-metals, but FWIW I can't reproduce your problem with plain lsp-mode. Here's what I did: 1. installed semgrep, so it's available in $PATH, 2. Opened a test.scala with this hello world content, 3. evaluated M-x lsp. I have semgrep started as expected, and no errors is being printed. semgrep version is 1.101.0.
